# Number of chains and antichains in a Hasse-Diagram.

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I want to know how to determine the number of chains and antichains of a poset from a Hasse-Diagram. Let's say that we have the following Hasse-Diagram:

[image]

Let's say that I want to know the number of chains and antichains which contain a minimum of $3$ elements. Of course, I could do it by hand (in this case there are $4$ chains and $7$ antichains) but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it more efficiently which I can also apply to a poset with a higher number of elements and relations.

Comment: I didn't read the question carefully, I see.  I just skipped over the "at least $3$ elements" part.

Comment: Sorry. I should've probably made it a bit more clear.

Comment: Not your fault at all.  I was careless.  Just to be sure though, if we had the chain $1\to3\to9\to27$ would we also  count the $4$ $3$-element subchains, $1\to3\to9$, $1\to3\to27$, etc.

Comment: Exactly. So you would count the two sub chains as well as the longest chain. Therefore, you would have $3$ chains which each have at least $3$ elements in each chain.

Comment: SkiMask - I cant reconcile your last comment with @saulspatz last comment.  If you have a chain $1 \to 3 \to 9 \to 27$, do you have _two_ or _four_ subchains of length $3$?  I think saulspatz is saying there are _four_ i.e. $1 \to 3 \to 9, 1 \to 3 \to 27, 1 \to 9 \to 27$ and $3 \to 9 \to 27$ (not to mention the overall length-$4$ chain).  Do you agree?

Comment: @antkam Yes, that what I was saying.  I assumed SkiMask just answered too fast.

Comment: @saulspatz - I agree with you that in the normal language of chains, a length $4$ chain should have four different length $3$ subchains.  However, if the OP wants to count only two such subchains (i.e. OP is using terminology imprecisely), then I _think_ the problem is actually easier: this becomes counting paths of certain hopcounts in a directed acyclic graph, and should be doable with repeated multiplications of the adjacency matrix.  That's why I ask -- to see if OP actually meant the easier problem.  :)